# Updating Primary Key table throws 'DbEntityValidationException' without changing and foreign key table values in Entity Framework 6

Tags: validation, entity-framework-6

Entity Framework is throwing a

> System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException

when I am updating the primary key if a table without updating foreign key table values. I even tried with `EntityState.Unchanged` on foreign key tables but exception persists.

```
public partial class ClientInfo
{
    public ClientInfo()
    {
        this.ClientAkaNames = new HashSet<ClientAkaName>();
        this.ClientContactDetails = new HashSet<ClientContactDetail>();
    }

    [Key]
    [System.Web.Mvc.HiddenInput()]
    public long ClientId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Client name is required.")]
    [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 10, ErrorMessage = "Client name must contain atleast 10 characters, and max. 100.")]
    public string ClientName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Postal address is required.")]
    [StringLength(200, MinimumLength = 10, ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid address.")]
    public string ClientPostalAddress { get; set; }

    public Nullable<int> Credits { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ClientAkaName> ClientAkaNames { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ClientContactDetail> ClientContactDetails { get; set; }
}

public partial class ClientAkaName
{
    [Key]
    public long ClientAkaNameId { get; set; }
    public long ClientId { get; set; }

    public string AkaName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> LastUpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> LastUpdatedBy { get; set; }

    public virtual ClientInfo ClientInfo { get; set; }
}

public partial class ClientContactDetail
{
    [Key]
    public long ClientContactId { get; set; }
    public long ClientId { get; set; }

    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    public string ContactEmailId { get; set; }
    public string ContactAlternateEmailId { get; set; }
    public string ISDCode { get; set; }

    public string ContactPhoneNo { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> LastUpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> LastUpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public virtual ClientInfo ClientInfo { get; set; }
}
```

And the code to save `ClientInfo` object using a generic repository pattern and unit of work:

```
    public string UpdateOClient(ClientInfo client)
    {
        try
        {
            unitOfWork.Repository<ClientInfo>().Update(client);
            unitOfWork.Save();
            return "1020";
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return "1021";
        }
    }
```

The error is thrown at `unitOfWork.Save();`. I checked the details of exception but no parameter or property is shown where the exception is thrown.

I even tried removing the relations in the class but the same error persists.

Help me with solution or a better approach.

Comment: The best solution would be to **not ever** update the primary key! The PK should be ideally set once and never modified after that.

Comment: I know that Key values cannot be set. I am setting other properties like Name and other text fields. I even checked the modelstate and everything is fine, but still the error persists.